# Saving And Loading Up A Highscore In Swift Using NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am having some problems while attempting to compare my score and highscore to see which one is bigger and then save it. I think the problem lies in the comparison and saving of the highscore and score. Help would be greatly appreciated!

```
//Comparison between score and highscore
if score > highscore {
let defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    highscore = defaults.valueForKey("highscore")?.integerValue ?? 0
    defaults.setInteger(score, forKey: "highscore")
    defaults.synchronize()
    highscoreString = String(highscore)
    highscoreLabel.text = highscoreString  }
```

Full Page Code - https://github.com/SRL311/Highscore/blob/master/Highscore
(Sorry about the confusing capitals and lowercases there)

Comment: It is not being saved when I reopen the page. Also, if you look at the link on the bottom I have multiple highscores on that page and it seems to be passing the scores down when it shouldn't be.

Comment: Use the debugger and step through the code and look at the values of your variables.

Comment: I didn't understand what is the issue you are talking about. But from your code `String(highscore)` it's not correct, it should be `String(score)`

Comment: 1. You are not assigning `score` to `highscore`. 2. There is no reason to get the old `highscore` from `NSUserDefaults `. 3. There is no need to `synchronize`.

Answer (score 5):

You can also create a new NSUserDefault property with a getter and a setter to automatically check if the score you are trying to save it is higher than the actual high score:

update: **Xcode 8.2.1 • Swift 3.0.2**

```
extension UserDefaults {
    static let highScoreIntegerKey = "highScoreInteger"
    static let highScoreDoubleKey = "highScoreDouble"
    var highScore: Int {
        get {
            print("High Score:", integer(forKey: UserDefaults.highScoreIntegerKey))
            return integer(forKey: UserDefaults.highScoreIntegerKey)
        }
        set {
            guard newValue > highScore
            else {
                print("\(newValue) ≤ \(highScore) Try again")
                return
            }
            set(newValue, forKey: UserDefaults.highScoreIntegerKey)
            print("New High Score:", highScore)
        }
    }
    func resetHighScore() {
        removeObject(forKey: UserDefaults.highScoreIntegerKey)
        print("removed object for highScoreIntegerKey")
    }
    var highScoreDouble: Double {
        get {
            return double(forKey: UserDefaults.highScoreDoubleKey)
        }
        set {
            guard newValue > highScoreDouble
            else {
                print("\(newValue) ≤ \(highScoreDouble) Try again")
                print("Try again")
                return
            }
            set(newValue, forKey: UserDefaults.highScoreDoubleKey)
            print("New High Score:", highScoreDouble)
        }
    }
    func resetHighScoreDouble() {
        removeObject(forKey: UserDefaults.highScoreDoubleKey)
        print("removed object for highScoreDoubleKey")
    }
}
```

---

testing in a Project (doesn't work in playground since Swift 2):

```
UserDefaults().resetHighScore()
UserDefaults().highScore       // High Score = 0
UserDefaults().highScore = 100 // New High Score = 100
UserDefaults().highScore = 50  // 50 < 100 Try again
UserDefaults().highScore       // 100
UserDefaults().highScore = 150 // New High Score = 150
UserDefaults().highScore       // 150
```

**Xcode 7.2 • Swift 2.1.1**

```
extension NSUserDefaults {
    var highScore: Int {
        get {
            print("High Score = " + integerForKey("highScore").description)
            return integerForKey("highScore")
        }
        set {
            guard newValue > highScore else { print("\(newValue) ≤ \(highScore) Try again")
                return
            }
            setInteger(newValue, forKey: "highScore")
            print("New High Score = \(highScore)")
        }
    }
    func resetHighScore() {
        removeObjectForKey("highScore")
        print("removed object for key highScore")
    }
    var highScoreDouble: Double {
        get {
             return doubleForKey("highScoreDouble")
        }
        set {
            guard newValue > highScoreDouble else { print("Try again")
                return
            }
            setDouble(newValue, forKey: "highScoreDouble")
            print("New High Score = \(highScoreDouble)")
        }
    }
    func resetHighScoreDouble() {
        removeObjectForKey("highScoreDouble")
        print("removed object for key highScoreDouble")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Read your code carefully and you should be able to find the errors.

1. You are not assigning `score` to `highscore`.
2. There is no reason to get the old `highscore` from `NSUserDefaults`.
3. There is no need to `synchronize`.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 2:** You have set an integer value in *userDefaults* so, you may try retrieve it using, `defaults.integerForKey(score, forKey: "highscore")`